# How to cut large video without video editing software (Windows)

Tags: video-editor

I have a large video that I need only a small portion of online, and then I want to edit and cut out some parts inside that portion of video online. How do I accomplish that without any special software except perhaps VLC or the likes?

I wary of downloading AVIdemux and other "free" stuff from the web.

I've had bad experience with Softonic, CNet and the likes and even SourceForge who used to be great but then started installing stuff that you can't get rid of, and that affect your system like changing your search page etc. (For some reason many times they are not defined as malware, but in some cases are, and then its even worse because online instructions tell you to download "removal" software which usually like a Trojan just wreaks havoc).

Maybe there's something on GitHub?

Comment: A common tool is avidemux. Get it from developer site. Also only careless old people get adware from installers, pay more attention.

Comment: Dear @jiggunjer there's nothing wrong with being old. And there is something very wrong with the websites that give you trojanware (they claim that its legit because they give you the option to skip). So if they allow themselves that behavior I cannot trust that what they give as freeware is clean. Not sure about Avidemux itself. Would be nice to hear what other users with knowledge can say what they think of it.

See http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=232194

Comment: I agree with you on both points. I just meant that nowadays most people have enough skill to avoid crapware while getting their freeware. It just takes some practice (also check out sandboxy).

Comment: Ooh sandboxy, didn't know about it. Thanks! 

Anyways, I would rather avoid going into a minefield and endangering everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to make multiple cuts and then join them or edit those cuts, you'll need a video editor to do it efficiently. Try [Shotcut](http://www.shotcut.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to say I found a way with VLC and youtube together: so I'm answering my own question. (But shotcut seems a legit open source from github, without those virus like programs that you can't get rid of, so thank you @Mulvya) Here's how to do it if you already have VLC downloaded (that one also comes with its trojans):

1. You set the recording to a specific location (tools / preferences: click on left bar's input / codecs... scroll down to  Files, Record directory or filename, and set that directory.
2. Now wait for your section of video - if you need several sections record each separately.
3. Go to recorded sections (they should be with a bit extra unneeded seconds, you'll cut precisely on youtube).
4. Upload the clips to youtube, then edit one of them. Use the Trim to cut in several locations, then stand on the sections you wish to remove and remove them. You can mix other videos into this one.
5. If you need the final movie downloaded use http://www.clipconverter.cc/

Comment: Just a note, this method might involve 4 transcoding steps (may affect quality). Also not clear what "standing on a section" means.

Comment: Recording is 1st. Uploading to Youtube is 2nd. I don't think the editing makes any difference in lossful quality. What's the 4th? If you try the youtube editing you'll easily see what "standing on a section" means.